# Objects are showing as transparent or reflective in the shader tab?

Tags: rendering, shaders

When I switch to the shader tab, my objects look like this:

[image: Default Cube in the shader tab. It is transparent and reflecting the environment.]

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing this and how to fix?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=mYqpBsBO" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/mYqpBsBO/) 

Like so?

Comment: in the file you share I just see a cube, not the object you show in your screenshot

Comment: Yes, it's the default cube. I opened a new file, switched to the Shader tab, and this is the result.

Comment: Do you mean the Shading workspace? I see the cube correctly, maybe it's a graphic card problem, I hope someone will understand

Comment: Switching the render engine from Eevee has partially fixed the problem - I'm still getting the weirdness above in material preview using Cycles, but not in the full render preview.